# Use facts gathered by ansible programmatically

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-facts

I'd like to write a Python program that uses the facts that Ansible gives me with `ansible HOST -m setup`.

When I call this, I get a response which makes it only almost pure JSON:

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup
localhost | success >> {
    // actual data
}
```

Is there some way to get this JSON response directly without parsing the shell output (which might not be too stable)? Could I even use Ansible directly in a Python 3 program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Python2 is OK for you, you can use the Ansible API directly. You can find detailled instructions here: http://docs.ansible.com/developing_api.html
It's really easy.

And alternate, shell centric way is to use jq. There is a quick intro here: http://xmodulo.com/how-to-parse-json-string-via-command-line-on-linux.html

Comment: Downvoted. This is a joke of an answer. If the asker found it "really easy" they wouldn't be here. Also, have you looked at the Ansible API?? It may be easy to you, having used it a while, but it is poorly documented and comes with a fairly steep learning curve. And there is no mention of accessing gathered facts on the page you referenced.

Answer (score 3):

## version [stable-2.2](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/55339cd0b43b38130cfc3c0e5278953a806796a8), [stable-2.3](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/44b3d67ef31b3c4c5d33c6f4289ce011e1bbe8fe), and 2.4+

The latest ansible releases for 2.2, 2.3, and 2.4 all support `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK` variable. To use it, you need to add an `ansible.cfg` file that looks like:

```
[defaults]
bin_ansible_callbacks = True
callback_plugins = ~/.ansible/callback_plugins
```

You can place it wherever you're using ansible. Then, you need to create the `callback_plugins` directory, if you haven't already. Finally, you need to add a custom json parser to the directory. I copied the json parser that is bundled with ansible to the `callback_plugins` directory, then edited a single line in it to make it work.

I found the `json.py` file by first executing `ansible --version`

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.4.0.0
    config file = /Users/artburkart/Code/ansible.cfg
    configured module search path = [u'/Users/artburkart/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
    ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
    executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
    python version = 2.7.13 (default, Jul 18 2017, 09:17:00) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)]
```

Then using the "ansible python module location" to find the `json.py`.

```
cp /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/json.py ~/.ansible/callback_plugins/
```

Finally I edited the `v2_runner_on_ok` function in the `json.py` file to look like this ([courtesy of armab on GitHub](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/26098#issuecomment-330804515)):

```
def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result, **kwargs):
    host = result._host
    self.results[-1]['tasks'][-1]['hosts'][host.name] = result._result
    print(json.dumps({host.name: result._result}, indent=4))
```

Once that was all set up, the command is very simple:

```
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json ansible all -i localhost, -c local -m setup | jq
```

If you always want to parse JSON output, you can add the following line to the end of the `ansible.cfg` file I described above.

```
stdout_callback = json
```

That way, you don't need to include the environment variable anymore.

## versions <= latest 2.2 stable

When querying against instances, I use the following command:

```
ansible all --inventory 127.0.0.1, --connection local --module-name setup | sed '1 s/^.*|.*=>.*$/{/g'
```

If you pipe the output into `jq`, as [leucos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125569/use-facts-gathered-by-ansible-programatically#answer-26128502) suggested, it happily parses the semi-valid JSON. For example:

```
ansible all -i hosts -m setup | sed '1 s/^.*|.*=>.*$/{/g' | jq -r '.ansible_facts.ansible_distribution'
CentOS
Ubuntu
```

Comment: This is what ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK for. Just set it to `json`.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov - You are aware the `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK` flag is only available in `ansible-playbook`, right? Just so the facts are clear: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/15050

Comment: Sorry for my brief comment. Yes, i'm aware of this. If you want to use json with `ansible` cli, you can copy json.py as ./library/minimal.py. See my [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38667680/2795592) answer

Comment: Since this is a question about `ansible` and not `ansible-playbook`, I think I'll leave my answer as-is. When https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/15050 is closed, I'll update my answer to reflect the new functionality.

Comment: It appears there will be no JSON output supported in ansible any time in the near future. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/15050#issuecomment-317078659

Comment: Nice, I'll try your solution out when ansible 2.4 is released.