# Callbacks for generic Ansible runs?

Tags: ansible

I have defined a callback like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import pprint

from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase


class JSONPrettyPrintCallback(CallbackBase):

    printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4, stream=sys.stdout)

    def log(self, host, category, data):
        # one json blob to rule them all
        self.printer.pprint({'host': host, 'category': category, 'data': data})
```

In my Ansible config, I have the path defined:

```
[defaults]
callback_plugins = callback_plugins/
```

However, when i run my module, I still see the default Ansible output:

```
10.0.0.1 | SUCCESS => {
    ...
}
```

I'm running it like this:

```
ansible all -u myuser -m script -a 'path/to/script.py'
```

Is there something I need to do to format my output properly?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replace Ansible standard output, you should set [stdout_callback](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#stdout-callback) parameter to your callback.

**Update:** stdout_callback parameter will affect only `ansible-playbook` CLI output, as correctly noted in the comments.

I've investigated [the code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.1.0.0-1/lib/ansible/cli/adhoc.py#L166) a bit, `ansible` CLI supports only `minimal` and `oneline` (if `-o` option is set) stdout callbacks.
The easiest way to change the output behavior is to place `./callback_plugins/minimal.py` in your playbook folder and modify it to your needs.
Or you can patch `adhoc.py` to be able to accept other stdout plugins.

Comment: Seems to only affect ansible-playbook and not ansible.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay you are right, I wasn't aware of this. I've updated my answer about possible ad-hoc solution.

Comment: Bug in `ansible` not respecting stdout_callback is fixed in newer versions and backported, e.g. 2.3.3 https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16194#issuecomment-311340681

Answer (score 4):

There was a bug reported https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16194 and `Ansible` CLI was just fixed in https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/26098 to respect custom `stdout_callback`.

To have custom callbacks working you need to specify both [`stdout_callback`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#stdout-callback) (`ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK` env) and [`bin_ansible_callbacks = Yes`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#bin-ansible-callbacks) (`ANSIBLE_LOAD_CALLBACK_PLUGINS` env).

The change should be backported to both Ansible 2.2 and 2.3