# Where can I find a list of alternative Ansible callback_plugins that alter the output?

Tags: ansible

Where can I find a list of alternative Ansible callback_plugins that alter the output?

The default output of Ansible is not very friendly as is wasting a lot of space and when you get an error the JSON output is making very hard to read stdout and stderror of the failed command.

Where can I find a list of alternative output plugins?

Answer (score 2):

You can grep ansible library:

```
$ grep "CALLBACK_TYPE = 'stdout'" ./ansible/plugins/callback/*.py
./ansible/plugins/callback/actionable.py:    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'stdout'
./ansible/plugins/callback/default.py:    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'stdout'
./ansible/plugins/callback/json.py:    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'stdout'
./ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py:    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'stdout'
./ansible/plugins/callback/oneline.py:    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'stdout'
./ansible/plugins/callback/skippy.py:    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'stdout'
```

Keep in mind that `ansible-playbook` CLI support all this types of stdout callbacks, while `ansible` CLI support only `minimal` and `oneline` (See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38667680/2795592) to workaround)