# How can I make Ansible show only errors in execution?

Tags: ansible

How can I make ansible show only errors inside of some playbook, or even when directly invoked?

I tried suppressing std output but that apparently didn't help, because execution errors seem to be put into standard output instead of error output on Linux.

```
ansible all -a 'some_command_I_want_to_know_if_it_crashes' 1> /dev/null
```

I see only errors from Python (exceptions etc.) but not errors from playbook (the red text).

Answer (score 3):

Use the official sample [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins) called [actionable.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/actionable.py).

Put it in the `callback_plugins` directory and enable stdout-callbacks in `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
stdout_callback = actionable
```

Just by enabling it you will get much less information in th output, but you can further modify the plugin code to suit your needs.

For example to disable messages on successful tasks completely (regardless if status is `ok` or `changed`) change:

```
def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result):
    if result._result.get('changed', False):
        self.display_task_banner()
        self.super_ref.v2_runner_on_ok(result)
```

to

```
def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result):
    pass
```

---

As [Konstantin Suvorov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239150/how-can-i-make-ansible-show-only-errors-in-execution/40243674#comment67754581_40243674) noted, the above `ansible.cfg` configuration method works for `ansible-playbook`.

For `ansible` output you can save the `actionable.py` as `./callback_plugins/minimal.py` to achieve the same results.

Comment: It is worth noting, that `stdout_callback` affects only `ansible-playbook`, but not `ansible`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38667680/2795592) for details.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like the `minimal.py` filename is predefined for `ansible` calls, but content-wise you can substitute it with any other sample plugin code, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Also there is `oneline.py` if you use `-o` option. But you can change it's content for your needs.

Comment: ok now an extra question, is it possible to run only /some/ `ansible-playbook` runs with this output? Or enable it on-demand

Comment: You can have a separate `ansible.cfg` (with different plugins enabled) in each project. Or you can define a path to the config file in an environment variable `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` and precede the `ansible-playbook` command.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the command with actionable callback

```
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=actionable ansible all -a 'some_command_I_want_to_know_if_it_crashes'
```

Comment: This will not work, see comments above about `stdout_callback` support.